# terraform s3 remote state file auto encryption

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, terraform

I have a terraform backend remote state hosted on S3.
I didn't set the encryption on the object level manually and didn't set anything on the S3 bucket level. My S3 bucket Default encryption is set to `None`

Wonder why the terraform state file is encrypted with `Server-side encryption AES-256` by default?

Please advise.

Comment: It could be that you encrypted the bucket when it was created.

Comment: Could you please check your bucket properties.

Comment: This is the terraform code to create he bucket.

`resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_state_s3" {
  bucket = "tf-state-s3"
  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "To test enable encryption on S3 Remote Terraform State Store"
  } 
}`

Any particular bucket properties you're trying to look for?

Comment: Hi can you please show the properties from the AWS console. It might have been set manually?

Answer (score 3):

Default encryption for the bucket is not enabled, but it looks like you enabled encryption for your AWS backend.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "THE_NAME_OF_THE_STATE_BUCKET"
    key     = "some_environment/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "us-east-1"
    encrypt = true
    kms_key_id = "THE_ID_OF_THE_KMS_KEY"
  }
```

If **kms_key_id** is not specified and `encrypt = true`, Terraform uses SSE-S3 (AES-256) by default. As a result, the state file is encrypted with AES-256.

Answer (score 1):

[sogyals429](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9768520/sogyals429)
As mentioned, the default encryption is disabled.
But the object itself is encrypted.

[image: disable default encryption]
[image]
[image]